# how to navigate rows in datatable using up and down keys in keyboard and using enter key i need to get whole data

Tags: datatable, navigation

i wanted to add one services from service list(MODEL VIEW).Row should highlight by using up and down keys and if i press the enter key on highlighted row, i need to get row data from their and set in to main  table (datatable).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUWLV.png